# How to programmatically check if a wcf service is stopped or not

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I am doing a Windows Phone 7 application which uses a wcf service to collect data relevant to the app. I need to give the user a message to try after sometimes if the service is temporary stopped. How can i do this?

Comment: define "stopped". There are lots of reasons that you may not be able to connect to a web service and you should probably handle all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe check if the service is online by sending a http request to it?

```
public static Boolean isSiteOnline(String url)
    {
        Boolean result = true;
        HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
        if (httpRes.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            result = false;

        httpRes.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Little old fashioned way. It would probably be much better to handle the exceptions. Read [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx)

Comment: If you experience a lots of downtime for the wcf service, then do both. First check if it is online and then handle the exceptions which may be thrown for different reasons.

Comment: Am not getting GetResponse() function.

Comment: is there any other way to check if the process is up and running? i'm trying your suggestion `GetResponse()` method but its taking much more time.